# NotSerializableException for `Map[String, String]` alias

Tags: scala, exception, serialization, akka

I'm trying to send an object to a remote actor and I got this exception:

```
ERROR akka.remote.EndpointWriter - Transient association error (association remains live)
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2
```

The object being serialized is a case class:

```
case class LocationReport(idn: String, report: String, timestamp: Option[String], location: Attr, status: Attr, alarms: Attr, network: Attr, sensors: Attr) extends Message(idn) {

  val ts = timestamp getOrElse location("fix_timestamp")

  def json =
    (report ->
      ("TIME" -> ts) ~
      ("location" -> location) ~
      ("alarms" -> alarms) ~
      ("network" -> network) ~
      ("sensors" -> ((status ++ sensors) + ("CUSTOMCLOCK" -> Report.decodeTimestamp(ts)))))
}
```

And `Attr` is a type re-definition:

```
type Attr = Map[String, String]
```

The `Message` class is pretty simple:

```
abstract class Message(idn: String) {
  def topic = idn
  def json(): JValue
}
```

I'm wondering if the type alias/redefinition is confusing the serializer. I think I'm using ProtoBuf serialization, but I do see `JavaSerializer` in the stacktrace.

**More Debugging Info**

I newed up a JavaSerializer and individually serialized each of the Maps. Only one (`alarms`) fails to serialize. Here's the toString of each of them:

This one failed:

```
alarms = Map(LOWBATTERY -> 1373623446000)
```

These succeeded:

```
location = Map(a_value -> 6, latitude -> 37.63473, p_value -> 4, longitude -> -97.41459, fix_timestamp -> 3F0AE7FF, status -> OK, fix_type -> MSBL, CUSTOMCLOCK -> 1373644159000)
network = Map(SID -> 1271, RSSI -> 85)
sensors = Map(HUMIDITY -> -999, PRESSURE -> -999, LIGHT -> -999  9:52 AM)
status = Map(TEMPERATURE_F -> 923, CYCLE -> 4, TEMPERATURE1_C -> 335, CAP_REMAINING -> 560, VOLTAGE -> 3691, CAP_FULL -> 3897)
```

Comment: The type alias has absolutely nothing to do with this. This is a runtime issue and type aliases exists only in compile time.

Comment: If you haven't defined protobuf protocols for your classes and are using those, then you aren't using ProtobufSerialization.

Comment: @ViktorKlang I changed it to JavaSerialization, it still doesn't work.  I think it has to do with serializing `Map`, and as @ghik points out, it's not due to the alias. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating the map that you are sending?

Comment: What's in the Message class you're extending?

Comment: @sourcedelica The maps are created with literal key value tuples, `Map("error" -> error, "status" > status, ...)`

Comment: @Noah I added more code, including the Message class

Comment: The `val ts` line looks a little fishy. If you get a `None` for timestamp and location doesn't have a `fix_timestamp` field then you'll get an exception in `MapLike`, not sure if that's what you're getting now.

Comment: @Noah, nice thought, but no. `timestamp` is `None` but `location("fix_timestamp")` is `3F0AE7FF` for the instance that's failing

Comment: @Noah, I updated the question with more debugging info. It looks like it might be coercing a string to an Int and then failing because it's too big to be an Int?

Comment: @sourcedelica I believe you're onto something. The failing map isn't created with literals. It uses `+` to concat pairs onto an accumulator map (tail recursion), essentially `Map() + ("k2" -> "v2") + ("k2" -> "v2")`. What were you thinking with this?

Comment: I'm wondering what this `scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2` thing is.

Comment: @sourcedelica It's created by `scala.collection.immutable.Map.apply(String, String)`, which looks like `Map("foo" -> "bar")`. It's strange to me, but then again I'm new to Scala...

Comment: @sourcedelica - I got it narrowed down. It fails when I do `toBinary(alarms.mapValues(_ + "~"))`. For some reason, the object that Map produces isn't serializable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that `Map.mapValues` produces an object that's not serializable. When alarms was created, it's run through something like `alarms.mapValues(hex2Int)`. The problem and workaround is described here:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7005

In short, the solution is to do `alarms.mapValues(hex2Int).map(identity)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this works in all cases but my workaround was simply to convert the map into a sequence (just `.toSeq`before the sequence) before serialization. `toMap` should give you the same map after deserialization.