# Map can not be serializable in scala?

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I am new to Scala. How come the "map" function is not serializable? How to make it serializable? For example, if my code is like below:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(1,4,3,5,2,3,5))

def myfunc(iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
  val lst = List(("a", 1),("b", 2),("c",3), ("a",2))
  var res = List[Int]()
  while (iter.hasNext) {
    val cur = iter.next
    val a = lst.groupBy(x => x._1).mapValues(_.size)
    //val b= a.map(x => x._2)
    res = res ::: List(cur)
  }
  res.iterator
}

data.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect
```

If I uncomment the line

```
val b= a.map(x => x._2)
```

The code returns an exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2, value: Map(1 -> 3))
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: a, type: interface scala.collection.immutable.Map)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: As far I can tell it is not reproducible on Spark 1.2.0 - 1.5.0. Could provide some configuration details? How do you execute this code?

Comment: Hi zero323, I ran this code directly in the Scala shell comes with Spark 1.5.  I also ran the code in the Scala Shell of Spark 1.0.1 and the same problem exists.

Comment: I suspect this isn't the actual code giving the error?  Is your `lst` really just a plain list in the actual code? Or another RDD?

Comment: Hi Paul, this is the simplified version of my code  used to demonstrate my problem (I have the same problem with the simplified code). In my exact code the parameter "iter" is a tuple, and lst = iter._2.

Comment: @Carter So just to be clear - you can actually reproduce the problem using this piece of code? Without returning `a` or `b` from the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotSerializableException for \`Map\[String, String\]\` alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709995/notserializableexception-for-mapstring-string-alias)

Comment: @zero323 yes, I can reproduce the same problem with this code in the scala console of Spark 1.5 (I downloaded the compiled Spark 1.5, unzipped it, and then use the "./bin/spark-shell" command to start the scala shell, and copied and pasted this piece of code to the shell).

Comment: Thats interesting... Have you tried solution proposed above?

Comment: Hi zero323, I have a look at the solution above, but still not very clear about how to do it. Does it mean if I add ".map(identity)" at the end of the command I commented out it will solve my problem?  But I tried the following: val b= a.map(x => x._2).map(identity), the same problem is still there.

Comment: Or do you have the same problem with the same code? if not could you tell me how you run it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try val a = lst.groupBy(x => x._1).mapValues(_.size).map(identity)

Comment: Still does not work by using val a = lst.groupBy(x => x._1).mapValues(_.size).map(identity)

Comment: [@eliasah](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah) Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @zero323 I have just saw this comment. (It seems like notifications are not triggered when the user is not already in the comments stack) I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: BTW: I had this issue also with .values, eg. myHashMap.values.toSeq . The solution with .map(identify) works also here

Answer (score 72):

It's well known scala bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7005 Map#mapValues is not serializable

We have this problem in our Spark apps, `map(identity)` solves the problem

```
rdd.groupBy(_.segment).mapValues(v => ...).map(identity)
```

Comment: That was my assumption as well but [according to OP it doesn't solve the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900862/map-can-not-be-serializable-in-scala?noredirect=1#comment53635061_32900862).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! I would never have figured this out. Why does this work?

Comment: @Mattew Because `mapValues` is lazy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474314/is-scala-mapvalues-lazy)

Comment: I know this may sound weird, but what goes in place of the (...) inside .mapValues(v => ...) ? I have a Map[String, List[Set[String]]]

Comment: Current link of the bug task/description: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7005

Comment: @DannyLiu what goes there doesn't matter. The point is that any call to `mapValues` will create a view that isn't serialisable. The fix is to append `.map(identity)`, so that the view is forced to become concrete.

Answer (score 5):

The actual implementation of the `mapValues` function is provided below and as you can see it is not serializable and creates only a view, not a proper existence of data and hence you are getting this error. Situation-wise `mapValues` can have many advantages.

```
protected class MappedValues[C](f: B => C) extends AbstractMap[A, C] with DefaultMap[A, C] {
    override def foreach[D](g: ((A, C)) => D): Unit = for ((k, v) <- self) g((k, f(v)))
    def iterator = for ((k, v) <- self.iterator) yield (k, f(v))
    override def size = self.size
    override def contains(key: A) = self.contains(key)
    def get(key: A) = self.get(key).map(f)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this same code in an application? I suspect this is an issue with the spark shell. If you want to make it work in the spark shell then you might try wrapping the definition of `myfunc` and its application in curly braces like so:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(1,4,3,5,2,3,5))

val result = { 
  def myfunc(iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
    val lst = List(("a", 1),("b", 2),("c",3), ("a",2))
    var res = List[Int]()
    while (iter.hasNext) {
      val cur = iter.next
      val a = lst.groupBy(x => x._1).mapValues(_.size)
      val b= a.map(x => x._2)
      res = res ::: List(cur)
    }
    res.iterator
  }
  data.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect
}
```

Comment: I only tried this code in Spark Shell. Looks like it is the problem with the Shell.

Comment: what is happening when we wrap it in a val? Why does that fix it?