# Is Scala mapValues lazy?

Tags: scala, dictionary, mapping, lazy-evaluation

When I call

```
System.err.println("Before")
System.err.flush()
val foo: Map[Int, T] = t mapValues (fn(_))
System.err.println(foo.head) //prevent optimiser from delaying the construction of 'foo' 
System.err.println("After")
System.err.flush()
```

with `fn` having a debug print statement inside, I get this output:

```
Before
...head item...
After
...debug print statement from fn...
...debug print statement from fn...
```

I don't understand why the debug print statements are being called after "After" is printed, and I don't understand why I'm getting it twice --- unless `mapValues` creates a lazy map?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes it is](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L265). It maps to an intermediate class that holds `fn` and doesn't evaluate until access (again and again).

```
def mapValues[W](f: V => W): Map[K, W] = new MappedValues(f)
```

Use a strict `map` if you don't want lazy evaluation. That is:

```
collection map { case (k, v) => (k, fn(v)) }
```

Comment: Crucial feature is that you don't need to rehash map after `mapValues`, because keys didn't change. With `map` from you example, compiler cannot give guarantees.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that the `MappedValues` implementation evaluates the function on every access -- different from a Scala `lazy val` that evaluates only once.
You might be seeing the output twice when stepping through the code.  Expanding the `val foo` in the debugger window will iterate over the values, calling function `fn` and generating debug output.

If you provide code for map `t` and function `fn`, then we might be able to help.

Comment: It's fine – it was mainly that (as always) unexpected behaviour was troubling and needed to be tracked down, rather than causing a concrete problem. But thank you for the offer of help.