# Method executing again and again in scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I've a list of zip codes of stores and I want to find out which is at minimum distance from a given user's zip code. For this, I've written some code in scala -

```
case class UserCityDistance(city:String, zip:String, distance:Double)

private def getUserLocation(user_loc:String, store_loc:String)={
    println(s"# Calculating distance between user_loc $user_loc AND warehouse_loc $store_loc #")
    // Code here to calculate distance between users and store
    // This will give 3 values - store city, store zip and distance from user's zip
    return UserCityDistance(city, zip, distance) 
}
```

I'm calling this method from the same class -

productStoreMap contains list of stores having a product (the key) and user_zip contains the zip code of user.

```
val userDistanceList = productStoreMap.mapValues(_.map(x=>getUserLocation(user_zip,x))) // Get distance of each store from user's location
println(s"# Distance lists obtained - $userDistanceList #")
val minStore = userDistanceList.mapValues(_.minBy(_.distance)) // Selecting the minimum distant store
println(s"# Minimum distant warehouse - ${minWarehouse} #")
```

Its working good. But after printing out # Distance lists obtained - SOME VALUES HERE #, its again starts calculating distance between user zip and each of the warehouse zip as before, just like lazy evaluation.

Is there any problem with my code or anything that I'm missing ?

EDIT -

productStoreMap is of type - Map[List[String], List[String]]

Is this causing this trouble ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Scala mapValues lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474314/is-scala-mapvalues-lazy)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474314/is-scala-mapvalues-lazy and on the sidenote see https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html