# Functional Programming: Get new Map from existing Map with changed value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have one map like

```
val strMap = Map[String, String]("a" -> "a1", "b" -> "b1") // Map(a -> a1, b -> b1)
```

and I want to create another map with same key but different value, based on value in strMap. For example

```
case class Data(data: String) {}
var dataMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Data]()
strMap.foreach (keyVal => {dataMap(keyVal._1) = Data(keyVal._2)})
val dataMapToUse = dataMap.toMap // Map(a -> Data(a1), b -> Data(b1))
```

but writing this in imperative style is causing issue like creation of "var dataMap", though I want to get immutable map. Because of this, I have to call *toMap* to get same.
How can I achieve same in functional programming?

Scala Version: 2.11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply use,

```
val dataMapToUse = strMap.map{case(k,v) =>(k -> Data(v))}
```

Comment: or even `strMap.mapValues(Data.apply)`

Comment: Don't even need the `apply`.  This works: `strMap.mapValues(Data)`

Comment: @AlekseyIsachenkov, one point against `mapValues` may be [laziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474314/is-scala-mapvalues-lazy).