# How to convert RDD[Array[String]] to RDD[(Int, HashMap[String, List])]?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, hashmap

I have input data:

```
time, id, counter, value
00.2,  1 , c1     ,  0.2
00.2,  1 , c2     ,  0.3
00.2,  1 , c1     ,  0.1
```

and I want for every id to create a structure to store counters and values. After thinking about vectors and rejecting them, I came to this:

```
(id, Hashmap( (counter1, List(Values)), (Counter2, List(Values)) ))
(1, HashMap( (c1,List(0.2, 0.1)), (c2,List(0.3)))
```

The problem is that I can't convert to Hashmap inside the map transformation and additionaly I dont't know if I will be able to reduce by counter the list inside map.

Does anyone have any idea?

My code is :

```
val data = inputRdd
          .map(y => (y(1).toInt, mutable.HashMap(y(2), List(y(3).toDouble)))).reduceByKey(_++_)
  }
```

Comment: Why RDD API not DataFrame/Dataset?!

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, untested:

```
import collection.mutable.HashMap

inputRdd
  .map{ case Array(t, id, c, v) => (id.toInt, (c, v)) }
  .aggregateByKey(HashMap.empty[String, List[String]])(
    { case (m, (c, v)) => { m(c) ::= v; m } },
    { case (m1, m2) => { for ((k, v) <- m2) m1(k) ::= v ; m1 } }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("00.2", 1, "c1", 0.2),
  ("00.2", 1, "c2", 0.3),
  ("00.2", 1, "c1", 0.1)
))

rdd.
  map{ case (t, i, c, v) => (i, (c, v)) }.
  groupByKey.mapValues(
    _.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map(identity)
  ).
  collect
// res1: Array[(Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Iterable[Double]])] = Array(
//   (1,Map(c1 -> List(0.2, 0.1), c2 -> List(0.3)))
// )
```

Note that the final `map(identity)` is a remedy for the [Map#mapValues not serializable problem](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7005) suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910318/6316508).

Comment: Why do you think about replacing underscores with `case`? Would that improve readability and so comprehension?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski, I generally prefer using case with more meaningful variables over tuple accessors for readability (especially when the tuple size is bigger than 2 and/or when the transformation involves grouping/positional shuffling).

Answer (score 0):

If, as you have mentioned, have `inputRdd` as

```
//inputRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at ....
```

Then a simple `groupBy` and `foldLeft` on the *grouped values* should do the trick for you to have the final desired result

```
val resultRdd = inputRdd.groupBy(_(1))
                          .mapValues(x => x
                            .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[String]]){(a, b) => {
                              if(a.keySet.contains(b(2))){
                                val c = a ++ Map(b(2) -> (a(b(2)) ++ List(b(3))))
                                c
                              }
                              else{
                                val c = a ++ Map(b(2) -> List(b(3)))
                                c
                              }
                            }}
                          )
//resultRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]])] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at mapValues at ...
//(1,Map(c1 -> List(0.2, 0.1), c2 -> List(0.3)))
```

changing `RDD[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]])]` to `RDD[(Int, HashMap[String,List[String]])]` would just be casting and I hope it would be easier for you to do that

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Why do you think about replacing `a.keySet.contains(b(2))` with `mutable.Map` and [getOrElseUpdate](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#getOrElseUpdate(key:K,op:=%3EV):V)?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thanks for the reply, getOrElseUpdate will return me value if the key is present or else value is the new operation but the scenario is like adding new list if the key is present. I am just confused on how your information might be of help to improve the answer ?