# Identify which object is not serializable in Apache-Flink

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-flink, serializable

I am writing a Flink transformer and I have a custom object `Histogram` with the following attributes:

```
case class Histogram(
  nRows: Int,
  nCols: Int,
  min: Int,
  step: Double,
  private val countMatrix: Array[ArrayBuffer[Double]],
  private val cutMatrixL1: Array[ArrayBuffer[Double]],
  val distribMatrixL1: Array[ArrayBuffer[Map[Int, Double]]],
  private val distribMatrixL2: Array[ArrayBuffer[Map[Int, Double]]],
  private val cutMatrixL2: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]])
  extends Serializable {
    ???
}
```

This is my `FitOperation`:

```
implicit val fitOp = new FitOperation[PIDiscretizerTransformer, LabeledVector] {
    override def fit(
                      instance: PIDiscretizerTransformer,
                      fitParameters: ParameterMap,
                      input: DataSet[LabeledVector]): Unit = {

      // get params...

      val metric = input.map { x ⇒
        // (instance, histrogram totalCount)
        (x, Histogram(nAttrs, l1InitialBins, min, instance.step), 1)
      }.reduce { (m1, m2) ⇒
        // Update Layer 1
        val updatedL1 = updateL1(m1._1, m1._2, instance.step, initialElems, alpha, m1._3)

        //         Update Layer 2 if neccesary
        val updatedL2 = if (m1._3 % l2updateExamples == 0) {
          updateL2(m1._1, updatedL1)
        } else updatedL1

        (m2._1, updatedL2, m1._3 + 1)
      }.map(_._2)

      //      instance.metricsOption = Some(metric)
    }
  }
```

This works well, but if I uncomment the last line: `instance.metricsOption = Some(metric)` I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet`

How could I find which object in my class `Histogram` is causing the problem? As far as I know `ArrayBuffer` is serializable, so is Map. Although I've found this SO question:

[Map can not be serializable in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32900862/1612432)

which says `.mapValues` is not serializable, but I am not using `.mapValues` anywhere.

Comment: Could you show me the complete code? It might be possible that you create the `fitOp` in a context where it captures a `DataSet` instance in its closure.

Comment: Sure, here it is:

Histogram: https://github.com/elbaulp/DPASF/blob/master/dpasf/src/main/scala/com/elbauldelprogramador/datastructures/Histogram.scala

Transformer: https://github.com/elbaulp/DPASF/blob/master/dpasf/src/main/scala/com/elbauldelprogramador/discretizers/PIDiscretizerTransformer.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to `instance.step` inside your `MapFunction`. `instance` is of type `PIDiscretizerTransformer` which cannot be serialized. Thus, you need to compute step outside of the `MapFunction` and pass the value into the function. Then your program should be serializable.

Comment: Thanks!, that was it. Before asking the question removed the call to `instance.step` in the map, but forgot that I was using it also in the next call (`reduce`) so I still was getting the error.